# Cmake target link libraries from relative path

Tags: c++, cmake

I have C++ project which compiles using cmake. 
I'm trying to link library using relative path and not absolute path. The code compiles fine, but has problem while linking the libraries.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(GMW)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0015 NEW)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -maes -mpclmul -fPIC")

SET (BOOST_ROOT $ENV{HOME}/boost_1_60_0/)
SET (BOOST_INCLUDEDIR $ENV{HOME}/boost_1_60_0/)
SET (BOOST_LIBRARYDIR $ENV{HOME}/boost_1_60_0/stage/lib)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system thread REQUIRED)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES($ENV{HOME} ${BOOST_INCLUDEDIR}
        ../../lib/OTExtensionBristol ../../lib/)

link_directories(/usr/ssl/lib/ ../../install/lib ${BOOST_LIBRARYDIR})

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp GMWParty.h Circuit.cpp Circuit.h MPCCommunication.cpp MPCCommunication.h GMWParty.cpp)
add_executable(GMW ${SOURCE_FILES})
add_library(gmw ${SOURCE_FILES})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(GMW ../../scapi.a gmp
        OTExtensionBristol
        ../../install/lib/libsimpleot.a
        boost_system boost_thread pthread crypto dl ssl z)
```

`cmake_policy(SET CMP0015 NEW)` Solved the problem for link directories.

How do I solve it for link libraries?

Comment: `I'm trying to link library using relative path and not absolute path.` - Why do you want relative path? Note that path passed to `target_link_libraries` and processed by the linker has nothing common with RPATH embedded into the executable and processed by the loader.

Comment: If the libraries are part of the cmake project, you can just use the target_link_libraries with the cmake lib subproject name instead of the file.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I know I can use absolute path, but I keep local copies of my project in different locations.

Comment: @liorko: `I keep local copies of my project in different locations.` - Use `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` for refer to source directory of the project: `target_link_libraries(GMW "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../install/lib/libsimpleot.a")`. So you project can be configured from any directory. Note, that once the project is configured, its source and binary directories cannot be moved in any case.

Comment: Have you tries to prefix `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` like `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../scapi.a`? Because relative paths would be relative to `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR`.

Comment: @Florian Thank you!, this is what I looked for.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you, it's worked!

Comment: @liorko Use Florians suggestion. "CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR" or "CMAKE_BINARY_DIR" should rarely ever be used. They interfere with users or yourself composing CMake projects from other CMake projects. Use "CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR" and "CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR" by default instead.

Comment: @utopia Thank you for your advice.